# Adding RegEx to Linq method syntax

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have the following linq code:

```
var join = enterpriseContext.Parties
         .Join(enterpriseContext.ActiveDealerContactsViews,
            p => p.party_id,
             v => v.Party_id,
             (p, v) => new { PartySite = p, View = v })
         .Where(p => p.PartySite.party_id == partyId)
```

And I would like to add another .where expression using a regex check, e.g.

.where (v => v.View.System_id.IsMatch(regEx));

But it does not compile.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Do you mean `.Where(c => Regex.IsMatch(v.View.System_id, "some-pattern"))`? But.... RegEx will **not** work with Entity Framework.

Comment: Yes. In my code, regEx is the regular expression object, but essentially, it's the same.